# What Notation is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When $p$ is prime, show that $v: Z^*_p \rightarrow U_2$

I know that the $Z_p$ is the elements $\{0,1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$ But what about the star on top of the $p$? Is that the group operation? Because it's supposed to be part of a ring. I'm just not too sure.

Comment: It's likely the group of units (in this case, $\{1,2,\ldots, p-1\}$).

Comment: Usually the $*$ means non-zero elements, or the elements with a multiplicative inverse... in this case, exactly the set that @Hayden, pointed out.

Comment: The answer is bad notation. I usually see $U_2$ for the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$; that's just $\{1\}$ here, but the [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253434/show-that-it-is-a-homomorphism) seemed to use it to mean $\{-1, 1\}$ which I would write as $U_3$, or better yet, $Z_3^*$ using the notation from the left hand side of the original. It's mixing $2$ different notations to talk about similar multiplicative groups, and using (at least one) in a nonstandard way.

Answer (score 2):

For a ring $R$, $R^*$ is defined as $\{r \in R: r \text{ is a unit}\}$. If $R$ is a field, then $R^* = R \setminus \{0\}$.

**//Edit:** … and $r \in R$ is a unit if there exists an $s \in R$ with $r \cdot s = s \cdot r = 1$.

Comment: The usual notation is $R^{\mkern1mu\times}$. Normally, with a star, it usually denotes the non-zero elements. When $R$  is a field, they are the same, of course.

Comment: @Bernard I've often seen $R^*$ denoting the group of units.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it was standard when I was a student. I think relatively recent, but the `×` notation is quite useful as there's no ambiguity about what is meant.

Comment: @Bernard Well, depending on the context, $R^\times$ could denote the multiplicative semigroup as well. There's no consensus on the subject.

Comment: @egreg: That's why most, if not all, notations must be explained at the beginning of a paper.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a star, It means the set of invertible elements in $Z_p$ and if you are considering the multiplicative group $Z_p$ then $[0]$ is the only element that is not invertible.

Thats why the number of elements in $Z_p^*$ is $p-1$

However, When considering $Z_n^*$ in general, you may have more elements that are not invertible, not just $[0]$

Example: $[2]$ in $Z_4$ is not invertible

If you want to test whether an element is invertible in $Z_n$ you just see if the greatest common divisor of that element and $n$ is 1

if the gcd is 1 then the element is invertible.

If not then it's not invertible