# Show that it is a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> For any abelian group $G$ we have $e_n: G \to G, e_n(g) = g^n$. By convention $e_0(g) = 1$. For a Field $F$ we have the subgroup $\{1,-1\} \leq F^*$. When $F$ is of characteristic $2$, this is the trivial group. When $p$ is prime show that $\omega = e_{(p-1)/2} : Z_{p}^* \to U_2$.

Okay, I understand that they are telling me for any group we have this function $e$ that is homomorphism n stuff.

I don't understand how $F$ is a field, first of all. The identity element of addition isn't in it.

Also, what exactly are they asking me? If I plug a $p$ into the equation it equals that map? Or if I take $e_p$?

Comment: The last sentence in the first paragraph is out of context. What is $\omega$?

Comment: I copied it verbatim. That's what I was thinking. I feel like something isn't very much in context

Comment: $\{1,-1\}$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense

Comment: Does anybody know exactly what is being asked me me to prove?

Comment: Yes. I do know what it is asking.

Comment: Don't keep me in suspense here, man. What is my task. :)

Comment: If the equation is a definition of $\omega$, then what you've written isn't a sentence.

Comment: I'm just copying what was given to me. I am confused about it myself.

Answer (score 1):

$\{1,-1\}$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field. Recall, by definition, the multiplicative group of a field is abelian.

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. The multiplicative group, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times$ has order $p-1$. Therefore any element to the power of $p-1$ is the identity.

The claim is that for any $g\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times$ then $g^{(p-1)/2}$ is either $1$ or $-1$.

Show that this map $g\mapsto g^{(p-1)/2}$ is surjective onto the set $\{1,-1\}$ for all $p\neq 2$. (as the case $p=2$ is trivial).

I can provide hints if you'd like.

Comment: isn't the addition operation also abelian in a field?

Comment: I would like to comment, this is essentially outlining the proof for Euler's Criterion on quadratic (non)residues.

Comment: @user121615 $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times$ is not an abelian group under addition, as it does not contain the $0$ element. This refers only to the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and only makes sense in the context of the multiplicative group.

Comment: Ahh, I catch your drift, thanks. I will try to tackle this

Comment: @user121615 Good luck!

Comment: I get the proof is p-1 is the identity. If any element to the p-1 is the identity, than we end up with $1^{1/2}$, which consequently equals 1 for any element greater than 2. But what I don't get is how any element raised to the p-1 power is equal to the identity. Let's do this for $Z_5$. Lets take the element 2. $2^4$ = 16. 16/4 = 4 which does not equal the identity. I don't divided by 5 do I? Because this set has p-1 elements it should take one less to cycle? My logic is that $Z_{5}^X has elements {1,2,3,4}, so it's mod 4 not mod 5. Is this incorrect reasoning?

Comment: @user121615 $2^4=16\equiv1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: @user121615 Modular arithmetic is a result of the quotient structure of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, not the individual elements being considered.

Comment: What about $2^2$ = 4.?

Comment: $2^2 = 4$ in $Z_{p}^*$

Comment: I mean $Z_{5}^*$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23215/discussion-between-eoin-and-user121615).